# AMIS30543 | DataSheet Understanding CIRCULAR TRANSLATOR TABLE

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor, electronics, stepper

I was reading the data sheet of AMIS-30543 stepper motor and I didn't understand fully what does this Circular Translator Table means, I have a couple of doubts

1. What does Circular Translator table Stands for.? How to read it .? pg:13
2. What does the current pairs can be projected approximately on a circle in Ix, Iy plane means.? pg:25

[image: TranslatorTable]

3. In the data Sheet it is given that **Changes on the NXT input will move the motor current one step up/down in the translator table (even when the motor is disabled:  = 0)**. So the changes happened in the table while the motor was disabled will reflect as soon as the motor become active.? Like if I give say 5 step input while the motor was disabled and when I make the motor enable , will the motor will move by itself to reach that position in the translator table.? pg:25

[Link to datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AMIS-30543-D.PDF)

Answer (score 1):

1. It describes the current going through the two coils of the stepper motor at each `step`.
2. I'm not quite sure, as I would think the last two diagrams should actually be squares. But for example, in the first image, you can see that the current in the X coil will steadily increase, while the current in the Y coil will steadily decrease. This will make the stepper rotate more slowly.

   In the second image, you can see that only the Y coil driver is at 100% in step 0. In step 1 both coils are at 100%. In step 2 coil Y is turned off. I think this is profile produces more torque, but is less smooth.
3. No. I you are, for example using full step mode, and the motor is in step 0. If you give it 3 steps forward  (while the motor is disabled) it would drive the coils (once you re-enable to motors) as described in the lookup table for step 3. Which in practice would mean the motor would rotate backward one step (instead of 3 steps forward).

In other cases, it could result in undefined behavior. Going from step 0 to step 2 could mean it would rotate clockwise, anticlockwise, or even not rotate at all.

Though in practice I don't think this would even be an issue, and disabling the motor, but still sending it step pulses is kind of silly.